# TextEdit print to pdf failure in RemoteViewServices

Tags: pdf, printing, textedit

I just started getting "error while printing" printing to a pdf from textedit
(i.e. Print > PDF > Save as PDF ...).  This has worked in the past (for years),
though a web search indicates it's a common problem, 
  e.g.    https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4459650

It does not happen when printing to pdf from Safari, and also does not happen when
logged in as a different user.  The console log says

```
2/11/13 1:02:32.547 PM TextEdit[95328]: *** Assertion failure in -[NSAccessoryWindow sendEvent:], /SourceCache/RemoteViewServices/RemoteViewServices-80.6/NSAccessoryWindow.m:144
2/11/13 1:02:32.548 PM TextEdit[95328]: window allowed unexpectedly
```

Some of the web posts have included these suggestions, which do not work for me (nor for 
the other people with the problem, generally)

- delete the textedit preferences (2 files in ~/Library/Preferences)
- clear the print cueue
- cmd-option-quit Textedit and restart the machine
- repair permissions and disk check

Seems like it's an unsolved problem, so fame and glory to someone who can advise.

The machine is running 10.8.5. Nothing has been updated recently, however 
I recall I was trying to look in the print options for something a few days ago.

Also curious, what is this RemoteViewServices?  Is this the API used to send our print jobs
directly to an agency in Washington?  More seriously, google has multiple
mentions of errors, but no explanation of what it actually is.